# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()Lorg/hibernate/Session;

Tags: hibernate, csv, spring-batch

I'm trying to integrate a batch with my application

i'm using hibernate-core-3.6.3 and hibernate-hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0 and spring-batch-core-3.0.1

And when I try to insert into the database when I run the batch this error appears.

Here is my spring-batch-context

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:context-model.xml"/>


<!-- JobRepository and JobLauncher are configuration/setup classes -->
<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean" />

<bean id="jobLauncher"  class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>

<!-- à voir comment récuperer le nom du fichier et le mettre au value -->
<bean id="multiResourceItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
    <property name="resources" value="file:C:/Temp/kk/xx.csv" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="flatFileItemReader" />
</bean>

<!-- ItemReader reads a complete line one by one from input file -->
<bean id="flatFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader"  scope="step">

    <property name="lineMapper">

        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">

            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <!-- Mapper which maps each individual items in a record to properties in POJO -->
                <bean class="ma.controle.gestion.springbatch.BatchFieldSetMapper" />
            </property>

            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <!-- A tokenizer class to be used when items in input record are separated by specific characters -->
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="delimiter" value=";" />
                </bean>
            </property>

        </bean>

    </property>

</bean>


<!-- ItemWriter which writes data to database -->
<bean id="databaseItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemWriter">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>


<!-- Optional ItemProcessor to perform business logic/filtering on the input records -->
<bean id="itemProcessor" class="ma.controle.gestion.springbatch.BatchItemProcessor" />

<!-- Optional JobExecutionListener to perform business logic before and after the job -->
<bean id="jobListener" class="ma.controle.gestion.springbatch.BatchJobItemListener" />


<!-- Actual Job -->
<batch:job id="batchJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="txManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="multiResourceItemReader" writer="databaseItemWriter"
                processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="10" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="jobListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>
```

And Here is my context-model

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd"
                         default-autowire="byName"  default-init-method="init">

<import resource="classpath:context-datasource.xml"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>ma.controle.gestion.modele.Batch</value>
        </list>

    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop> 
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

and here is my context-datasource

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/controlegestion" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

Now, the exception happens, when I was trying to test if everything is set up correctly and I can write data from csv to database.

Also, here's my whole stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()Lorg/hibernate/Session;
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemWriter.doWrite(HibernateItemWriter.java:134)
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemWriter.write(HibernateItemWriter.java:113)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:274)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:199)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:162)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:141)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
at ma.controle.gestion.bean.batch.BatchExcelBean.uploadFile(BatchExcelBean.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:279)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUpload.broadcast(FileUpload.java:319)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:755)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.primefaces.barcelona.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:32)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does anyone know what's wrong here? Please help me out, I've been stuck here for hours.

Thanks!

Comment: You're using hibernate 3.6.3, which is 6 years old, with spring batch 3.0.1, which is 3 years old, and has a dependency on hibernate 4.2.12.Final.

Comment: @JBNizet so I need to change hibernate 3.6.3 to hibernate 4.2.12.Final ? 
I have a great phobia of change of version I always have the impression that nothing will continue to work ? 
And if I change the version of hibernate, compatibility problems will not happen ?

Comment: I can't make any guarantee. I don't know what your code does with Hibernate. Read the documentation on how to migrate. But after 6 years, it's time you move on. Update everything to the latest **compatible** versions, and read the migration guides.